# Mockito with Springboot: Use a different instance instead of mocking a method

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

In Mockito we can mock a method, but I'm wondering is it possible to use a different instance altogether?

More especially in my code, I `Autowired` a `Clock` as a private field and while testing I want to just use `Clock.systemDefaultZone()`. I don't want to mock a specific method of it.

The following is my unit test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
public class FooTest extends TestCase {

    @Mock
    private Clock clock;

}
```

Comment: you can't mock static methods using mockito. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Comment: You don't need a mock then. All you need is `new Foo(Clock.systemDefaultZone())`. Note that your 3 Spring annotations serve no purpose at all since your test doesn't run with the spring runner. You're mixing mockito annotations for unit tests with spring annotations for Spring integration tests.

Comment: Existing code doesn't do a constructor injection. It used private field injection

Comment: Then fix it. One of the roles of tests is to detect bugs and bad design, and to improve the quality of the code.

Comment: @JBNizet I ended up following your advice. Thank you.